# Python, calling subclass method from abstract base

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

I am trying to create a base abstract class and sub classes to abstract out access to the backend database. One subclass will be SQLAlchemy and the other MongoDB or other nosql. The following is a very simple example. In the base class I need a deleteObject for each type of object because noSQL implementations will require this, however, anything using SQLAlchemy just needs a single delete method. I want to save myself typing by having the following methods for each type of object in the abstract base. If this worked I wouldn't have to define deleteObject for every object type in the SQLAlchemy subclass, because the base abstract will just pass it to the private __delete function. Unfortunately, when I call deleteUser it does go to the abstract base function but the call to self.__delete(user) goes to the abstract function even though the subclass defines this function. Is there a way to ensure function calls in the abstract implementation go to the subclass when the subclass defines an implementation of that function?

```
@abc.abstractmethod
def deleteUser(self, user):
    """Delete an user from the backend database"""
    print('abstractmethod')
    self.__delete(user)

@abc.abstractmethod
def __delete(self, object):
    print('dont go here')
```

Comment: Sounds like polymorphology, and it should just work that way by default in Python

Comment: @duffymo I don't see the misunderstanding. Children override the __delete method, OP expects deleteUser to call that overridden method. Seems like normal inheritance to me?! Maybe I did not understand the question, what did you understand that made you write that comment?

Comment: I read it to say that the OP wanted the parent to know about child implementations.   Perhaps I misunderstood.  If he wants Python to act the way it should, then why the question?

Comment: @duffymo, I don't know what you are reading but what you said "The parent can provide default behavior that all children inherit but can override as they choose" is exactly what I am doing. The default behavior for all the individual deleteObjectName functions is just to call the subclass's implementation of delete(object). The issue was just that I had two underscores under the function name "__delete" instead of "_delete". Maybe try being less rude in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't name your methods with two `__` like in `.__delete`. This is not for "private" methods, regardless of the misleading documentation you may have read - this just causes the method name to be mangled with the class name it is declared in.

So, a call to `self.__delete` on a subclass will try to find a `.__delete` on that subclass, and only there, and will never call the same method on the superclass - and the converse is also true: if a you have such a call on the abstract superclass, the subclass method is never called, becuase internally they are renamed to include the class names as prefix.

Just use a single `_` and things should start working as you expect.

Comment: You are correct sir. That you very much. Python is not my native language, I appreciate your help.